# How do I fix 'cannot convert from method group to 'Func<AsyncCallback, object, IAsyncResult>'?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, xamarin

```
try
    {
      var login = ToServiceLogin(lgParameters);
      await Task.Factory.FromAsync(loginOperation.BeginLogin,
loginOperation.EndLogin, lgParameters, TaskCreationOptions.None);

    }
    catch (FaultException fe)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(@"          {0}", fe.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(@"              ERROR {0}", ex.Message);
    }
```

Compile error occurs on the first parameter of `Task.Factory.FromAsync`. I've read up on a couple of threads regarding similar issue none seems to be helping they all refer to this having a different signature. Please point me to the right direction.

**EDIT With Signature**

BeginLogin Signature

```
IAsyncResult BeginLogin(PRPClockingXamarin.PRPServiceMobile.LoginParameters loginParams,
                         AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState);
```

Comment: What's the type of `BeginLogin`, `EndLogin` and `lgParameters`? I would start by specifying the type parameters to `FromAsync` to get a more specific error message.

Comment: What is the Type of loginOperation?

Comment: It's clear form the error that BeginLogin does not have the right signature.

Comment: Please include the signature of `BeginLogin` and `EndLogin` so that it's easier to provide a meaningful answer.

Comment: The type for loginOperation is the interface of my WCF service.

Comment: @spender just edited with the signature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a long terse list of overloads but it seems it won't match your

```
IAsyncResult BeginLogin(
    LoginParameters loginParams,
    AsyncCallback callback, 
    object asyncState);
```

as the argument for

```
  Func<TArg1, AsyncCallback, object, IAsyncResult> beginMethod,
```

So I would suggest specifying the Type argument for `Targ1`,

```
FromAsync<PRPClockingXamarin.PRPServiceMobile.LoginParameters> (...)
```

also verify that lgParameters is of the correct type.

Comment: This worked I no longer have the error, thank you. The issue now is that it says my LoginResponse has the wrong return type. Any Idea where I could be going wrong?

Comment: I don't see any LoginResponse

Comment: LoginResponse is part of the     EndLogin signature    PRPClockingXamarin.PRPServiceMobile.LoginResponse EndLogin(System.IAsyncResult result);

Comment: I think you need yet another overload, [`FromAsync<TArg1, TResult>(Func<TArg1, AsyncCallback, Object, IAsyncResult>, Func<IAsyncResult, TResult>, TArg1, Object, TaskCreationOptions)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321447(v=vs.110).aspx)  .

Answer (score 0):

When using `FromAsync`, I usually recommend setting up the parameters as: begin method, end method, begin method arguments (except callback/state), and null. The final null is for the state:

```
await Task.Factory.FromAsync(loginOperation.BeginLogin, loginOperation.EndLogin,
    lgParameters, null);
```