# How to convert expression signature to be applicable with `It.IsAny` of `Moq`

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11502368/6844481) I've tried to something similar and mock an interface of:

```
public interface IGetRepository<TEntity>
{
    IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null);
}
```

This is my unit test method:

```
IEnumerable<EventModel> expectedList = return new List<MyModel>() 
{
    new MyModel()
    {
        Id = 0
    }
}

using (var _mock = AutoMock.GetLoose())
{
    var repositoryMock = _mock.Mock<IGenericRepository<EventModel>>();
    repositoryMock
        .Setup(items => items.Get(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<EventModel, bool>>>))
        .Returns(() => expectedList);
}
```

But the `It.IsAny<Expression<Func<EventModel, bool>>>` create an error message of:

> cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Expression>'

Already read these similar questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479870/how-do-i-fix-compiler-error-cannot-convert-from-method-group-to-system-delega),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41545772/how-do-i-fix-cannot-convert-from-method-group-to-funcasynccallback-object-i),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35321100/cannot-convert-from-method-group-to-funcstring-string-bool) , so I guess the my issue is different signature, if so **how do I convert this signature to be applicable with `It.IsAny` of `moq`**?

Comment: Are you missing parentheses, `items.Get(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<EventModel, bool>>>()))`?

Comment: Try taking `Expression` out of the `Is.IsAny` type

Comment: Also your question states you want to use `It.Is` but your example uses `It.IsAny`. Which one are you trying to use?

Comment: Hey @Johnny , this is kind of awkward, but I was missing the parentheses, I was not familiar with this syntax. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try this

```cs
var expectedList = new List<EventModel>()
            {
                new EventModel()
                {
                    Id = 0
                }
            };

            {
                var repositoryMock = new Mock<IGetRepository<EventModel>>();
                repositoryMock
                    .Setup(items => items.Get(It.IsAny<Func<IQueryable<EventModel>, IOrderedQueryable<EventModel>>>()))
                    .Returns(() => expectedList);
            }
```